# PHP fpm - value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have a server running LEMP stack that hosts a wide range websites. During the night, all the sites got shutdown and the message "502 bad gateway" Is displayed. I followed the stream of errors and concluded that php7.4-fpm was the issue. I need help to figure out how to solve the error below.

NOTE: *During the night, no updates or changes has been made to the system*

```
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-07-27 09:35:38 CEST; 7s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 1561620 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
    Process: 1561621 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 74 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1561620 (code=exited, status=78)

Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal php-fpm7.4[1561620]: [27-Jul-2021 09:35:38] ERROR: [/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf:98] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal php-fpm7.4[1561620]: [27-Jul-2021 09:35:38] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal php-fpm7.4[1561620]: [27-Jul-2021 09:35:38] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 09:35:38 Ubuntu-2010-groovy-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

I'm grateful for any ideas that you could have!

Comment: check /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 98

Comment: @GabrieleMartini Did check line 98 in the config file, but it does not say anything about ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY. The line follows: 98: grub.d networkd-dispatcher tmpfiles.d. Seems like it's just a list of processes or something.

Comment: @EricQvarnström ZEND_IN_PARSER_ENTRY is not a configuration parameter for the php pool, but a variable from the parsing process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I solved this issue by removing php7.4-fpm and installing it again. However, the problem still remains. Why did php7.4-fpm suddenly stopped working?

Comment: You must have used `pm.max_children: 100` instead of `pm.max_children = 100`. You must have copied it from a cpanel conf. During you re-installation you must corrected it. Note the use of colons instead of equal sign.

Comment: Good call @NgatiaFrankline - removing the php74-php-fpm package does delete the `www.conf` file, and reinstalling it then installs a fresh out-of-the-box file with no syntax errors.  If this is the case, you should have a `www.conf.rpmsave` file left from the uninstall in the config folder (in your case `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d`) which you can diff against the current `www.conf` to see what the error probably was. @Eric is that still lying around on your server?

Answer (score 11):

Just an idea, as I had the same error today setting up a fresh Alma linux server with `httpd` and `php74-php-fpm` from the remi repository.

I suggest the root cause of your problem was that the config had been altered some time before your shutdown, and that bad config then lurked causing no immediate problem.  At the time of the problem your servers were restarted for some reason, maybe an overnight job run by someone else, a regular update of system packages leading to daemons being restarted, or a power failure.  When they tried to start up again, they used the current config, which was by that time corrupt.

In my case I was editing the FPM config file `/etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.d/www.conf` and accidentally used a `#` character for a comment, e.g. `# My changes`.  On restarting the server, I got the same `value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY` error message in the journal.  The line numbers mentioned did not help, they basically referred to how `php-fpm.conf` includes every file in `php-fpm.d` which happens to include `www.conf` but didn't specify which line had the error.

The fix in my case was to use the correct `;` (semicolon) character, and not a `#`, for comments in `www.conf`.

This may not have been your case but I hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Seems like a logical explanation of what happened. Even though my problem is solved a long time ago, I still think this was a valuable input, thanks :)

Comment: yes , removing # (replacing with ;) did the trick !